# How to close a form launched from Main() without cross-thread errors

Tags: c#

I have an Windows form application that can be called from command line or used as a GUI. The command line options are only for scheduling the program to run saved tasks, so I don't want the GUI to launch if the command line options are used.

```
static void Main()
{
    //code to parse the command line options
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    try
    {
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
}

public MainForm()
{
    //Loading data from a file into the form.
    If (ArgumentList.Length >0)
    {
        //do command line-requested tasks
        this.close();
    }
    else
    {
        //do GUI tasks
    }
}
```

How do I close the MainForm window without making a instance of ObjectDisposedException be thrown? If I use anything after

```
Application.Run(new MainForm());
```

it doesn't run because that form is opened and nothing runs after that line until the form is closed. I've tried

```
this.Hide();
```

instead of

```
this.Close();
```

but this.Hide() doesn't seem to do anything in this case, as the form still shows. I know that I shouldn't try to close a form from within the form (cross-threading), but if I don't want the GUI form to show if called from command line.

Answer (score 2):

You should move that code to `Main()`, and avoid the form entirely if you don't need it.

Comment: I originally had it in Main(), but Main() is static and that prevents me from some of the processing MainForm() does. The form is a GUI that the users prepare information in. Running from command line is just so saved work can be run on a scheduled task.

Comment: @Phoenix14830: You should refactor your code to separate the business logic from the UI, and move it into a separate class, called from both `Main()` and the form.

Comment: Separating the logic could be an option, but doesn't answer the issue of  "How to close a form launched from Main() without cross-thread errors". Performing this.Close() from within the form will trigger the ObjectDisposedException, and that exception could be handled (very poor way to write code) but I'm looking for an option similar to that, only closing gracefully. Refactoring to separate the BU from UI wouldn't fit in the project timeline. Is there a way for a form to close itself that doesn't cause problems to the calling Main() program?

Comment: @Phoenix14830: Set a property in the ctor, then check that property before calling `Application.Run()`.